# Why vscode vue.js generates 4 different files (html, css, ts, spec.ts), instead of generating a .vue file (when I use generate component)?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I simply do not understand why vscode generates 4 files for a new vue.js component, and not generates any .vue files. How is these four files are related to a .vue file?

Comment: generates means you are build your project as spa(single page application) that will be able to run on client site directly as a serverless application like simple static html page

Comment: Then in case of SPA there is no need for .vue file? I am totally confused...

Comment: spa generates serverless static site that can run in client site by using browser, so browser doesn't know the .vue file, it's only know html,css,js etc. that's why generate command trans-pile(convert) all .vue and related things to html,css, js etc.

Comment: Thank you. Then where .vue file is running? It should be running also in the browser, shouldn't it? Or it is running on the server side? Sorry, i am getting more and more confused.